# Android.Media.MediaRecorder - delay when recording audio, with sections of silence

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

Please help solve the problem. To record an audio file, I use Android.Media.MediaRecorder. As a result, I get a section with silence 650 milliseconds at the beginning and at the end of the file. And it turns out that part of the phrase at the beginning and at the end is not recorded, only silence.

```
public static async Task Record(CancellationToken token)
    {
        try
        {
            var filename = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/temp.amr";
            var tmp = new Java.IO.File(filename);
            if (tmp.Exists()) tmp.Delete();
            var recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
            recorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.AmrNb);
            recorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);
            recorder.SetOutputFile(filename);
            recorder.Prepare();
            recorder.Start();
            try
            {
                var div = MAX_RECORD_TIME / 100;
                for(int i=0; i<div; i++)
                {
                    IncrementProgressBar(100 / div);
                    await Task.Delay(div, token);
                }
                fSave = true;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
            recorder.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string s = context.GetText(Resource.String.err_unexpected) + "\r" + e.Message;
            handler.ToastMessage(s, ToastLength.Short);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found a solution using RehersalAudioRecord. But this does not suit me, since I need to record in the `amr` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem cannot be adressed through code, It seems like it is a hardware problem.
You can see the same delay in the default Camera app, which also uses `MediaRecorder`.
Unfortunately some device will behave differently.

The Solution is to use the `AudioRecorder` class which is by far more flexible since it is closer to the hardware

Comment: OK. Only I did not find an encoding solution in the `AMR` format. And class AudioRecorder performs recording in an uncompressed format `WAV`. Then I need to somehow recode from `WAV` to `AMR`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for myself. The following code is working, it may be useful to someone.

```
    public static async Task Record(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/wav.pcm";
        System.IO.Stream outputStream = System.IO.File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bWriter = new BinaryWriter(outputStream);
        var audioBuffer = new byte[8000];
        var audRecorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.Mic, 8000, ChannelIn.Mono, Encoding.Pcm16bit, audioBuffer.Length);
        while(audRecorder.State != State.Initialized) { }
        audRecorder.StartRecording();
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                var audioData = await audRecorder.ReadAsync(audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);
                bWriter.Write(audioBuffer);
                IncrementProgressBar(1);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.Out.WriteLine("INFO: " + ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
        outputStream.Close();
        bWriter.Close();
        audRecorder.Stop();
        audRecorder.Release();
        fSave = true;
    }
    public static async Task Play(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/wav.pcm";
        var audBuffer = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filename, token);
        var bufferSizeInBytes = audBuffer.Length / 2;
        AudioTrack audioTrack;
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetLegacyStreamType(Android.Media.Stream.Music)
                                                                    .Build();
            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat.Builder().SetChannelMask(ChannelOut.Mono)
                                                            .SetEncoding(Encoding.Pcm16bit)
                                                            .SetSampleRate(8000)
                                                            .Build();
            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(attributes, format, bufferSizeInBytes, AudioTrackMode.Stream, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            audioTrack = new AudioTrack(Android.Media.Stream.Music, 8000, ChannelOut.Mono,
                                        Encoding.Pcm16bit, bufferSizeInBytes, AudioTrackMode.Stream);
        }
        audioTrack.Play();
        await audioTrack.WriteAsync(audBuffer, 0, bufferSizeInBytes*2);
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(((bufferSizeInBytes/8000)-1)*1000, token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        audioTrack.Stop();
        audioTrack.Release();
    }      
    public static async Task SaveAsAmr()
    {
        var encoder = MediaCodec.CreateEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MimetypeAudioAmrNb);
        MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
        format.SetString(MediaFormat.KeyMime, MediaFormat.MimetypeAudioAmrNb);
        format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeySampleRate, 8000);
        format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyChannelCount, 1);
        format.SetInteger(MediaFormat.KeyBitRate, 7936);
        encoder.Configure(format, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.Encode);

        try
        {
            Java.IO.File pcmFile = new Java.IO.File(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/wav.pcm");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pcmFile);
            Java.IO.File armFIle = new Java.IO.File(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "/wav.amr");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(armFIle);
            fos.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("#!AMR\n"));
            encoder.Start();

            var tempBuffer = new byte[8000];
            var hasMoreData = true;
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo outBuffInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            double presentationTimeUs = 0;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;

            do
            {
                int inputBufIndex = 0;
                while (inputBufIndex != -1 && hasMoreData)
                {
                    inputBufIndex = encoder.DequeueInputBuffer(0);
                    if (inputBufIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        Java.Nio.ByteBuffer dstBuf;
                        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                        {
                            dstBuf = encoder.GetInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dstBuf = encoder.GetInputBuffers()[inputBufIndex];
                        }
                        dstBuf.Clear();

                        int bytesRead = await fis.ReadAsync(tempBuffer, 0, dstBuf.Limit());
                        if (bytesRead == -1)
                        { // -1 implies EOS
                            hasMoreData = false;
                            encoder.QueueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, 0, (long)presentationTimeUs, MediaCodecBufferFlags.EndOfStream);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                            dstBuf.Put(tempBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            encoder.QueueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, bytesRead, (long)presentationTimeUs, 0);
                            presentationTimeUs = 1000000L * (totalBytesRead / 2) / 8000;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Drain audio
                int outputBufIndex = 0;
                while (outputBufIndex != (int)MediaCodecInfoState.TryAgainLater)
                {
                    outputBufIndex = encoder.DequeueOutputBuffer(outBuffInfo, 0);
                    if (outputBufIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        Java.Nio.ByteBuffer encodedData;
                        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                        {
                            encodedData = encoder.GetOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            encodedData = encoder.GetOutputBuffers()[outputBufIndex];
                        }
                        encodedData.Position(outBuffInfo.Offset);
                        encodedData.Limit(outBuffInfo.Offset + outBuffInfo.Size);
                        byte[] outData = new byte[outBuffInfo.Size];
                        encodedData.Get(outData, 0, outBuffInfo.Size);
                        fos.Write(outData, 0, outBuffInfo.Size);
                        encoder.ReleaseOutputBuffer(outputBufIndex, false);
                    }
                }
            } while (outBuffInfo.Flags != MediaCodecBufferFlags.EndOfStream);
            fis?.Close();
            fos?.Flush();
            fos?.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine("INFO: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```